# Datepicker not visible

Tags: forms, calendar

I am unable to use datepicker with popup forms enabled - calendar does not appear active on top of the form but underneath (discovered after reducing and moving the form around). It works with popup forms disabled. Help, please!

[image].

Using WP 4.7.3, CiviCRM 4.7.17

Comment: Interesting - works for me with 4.7.17 and Drupal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have a WP plugin installed which is interfering. Note the weird double-icons in the top-right of your screenshot. Definitely something extra going on there.

Check this list of [Wordpress Plugins Incompatible with CiviCRM](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=120029201). Your culprit may be listed. Otherwise, disable all plugins, and, assuming that solves your problem, re-enable them one-at-a-time to discover the culprit.

Comment: Culprit found,  'Indeed Social Share & Locker Pro' plugin - it comes bundled with the theme, deactivating it resolves the problem, thanks Coleman! I just have to see if I can work fix it or just take it out completely. The theme is Candidate

Answer (score 1):

Candidate theme comes with 'Indeed Social Share & Locker Pro' plugin which seems to be conflicting with CiviCRM